# java mouselistener on Line2d vector

Tags: java, graphics, mouseevent, graphics2d

I am not very experimented with listeners. I have a Vector of Line2D (representating a floorplan walls). I draw them in a JFrame.

I try to set a listener on those lines to be able to set them (change color etc) on click.

I am lost because I don't really know where to put the listener. I tried many things I found on many forums but nothing works really.

Thanks.

Edit1:

hi thank you for your answer it's a kind of big projects with many classes so i will post the code and describe how it wokrs . First . I import an image with a floorplan. I have a class with Actions that extends AbstractAction. I use opencv for for lines extraction . I store the extracted lines in a Vector of Walls (class i created).

```
 Vector<wall> walls
```

And here is my wall class

```
//a wall is represented by 2 points (pInitial and pFInal)
private Point pInitial, pFinal;
private double wallAttenuation;
private int wallType;


 public wall(Point p1, Point p2) {
// p1 is lower by the height than p2
if (p1.getY() > p2.getY()) {
    pInitial = p2;
    pFinal = p1;
} else {
    pInitial = p1;
    pFinal = p2;
}
}

//method to set the attenuation of the wall
public void setWallAttenuation(double a) {
    wallAttenuation = a;
}

//methods to set both ends of the wall

 public void  setPInitial(Point P1) {
 pInitial.x=(int)P1.getX();
 pInitial.x=(int)P1.getY();

}

public void  setPFinal(Point P2) {
   pFinal.x=(int)P2.getX();
   pFinal.x=(int)P2.getY();
}

//methods to get wall attributes (attenuation , ends and type)
public double getWallAttenuation() {
return wallAttenuation;
}

 public Point getPInitial() {
   return pInitial;
 }

 public Point getPFinal() {
    return pFinal;
  }

  public void setWallType(int type) {
     wallType = type;
  }

   public int getWallType() {
      return wallType;
  }
```

now in my importAction class, and after processing I have this vector of walls (each wall defiened by start and end point . After that , I open a new Frame in which i draws the lines. I want to be able to click on each wall for further modifications.

First i tried to create a Frame class with mouse event handling like this :

```
public class CreateJFrameWindowWithMouseEventHandling extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener,MouseListener {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public CreateJFrameWindowWithMouseEventHandling() {
       setTitle("Walls calibration");
      addMouseListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      int x = e.getX();
     int y = e.getY();
     System.out.println("Mouse Clicked at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
   }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
     int x = e.getX();
     int y = e.getY();
     System.out.println("Mouse Entered frame at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      int x = e.getX();
      int y = e.getY();
      System.out.println("Mouse Exited frame at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
   }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   int x = e.getX();
   int y = e.getY();
   System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
   int x = e.getX();
   int y = e.getY();
   System.out.println("Mouse Released at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
   }

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  @Override
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
  int x = e.getX();
   int y = e.getY();
   System.out.println("Mouse  at X: " + x + " - Y: " + y);
   repaint();

  }


  private static void createAndShowGUI() {

  //Create and set up the window.

  JFrame frame = new CreateJFrameWindowWithMouseEventHandling();

  //Display the window.
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
```

but i guess it wasnt the right solution . next thing i tried was to create JPanel browse the vector , draw the current line and add a listener. to check if it works i change the cursor if the mouse is over a line :

```
   JFrame wallsEdit = new JFrame("Walls Calibration");                     
   wallsEdit.add(new JPanel() {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
              for(int i=0;i<walls.size();i++)
              {
                  Point p1 = walls.get(i).getPInitial();
                  Point p2 = editor.walls.get(i).getPFinal();

                  g2.setColor(Color.black);
                  g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                  g2.drawLine((int)p1.getX(),(int)p1.getY(), (int)p2.getX(),(int)p2.getY());

                  walls.get(i).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                           public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                            Point CursorPoint= MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                  double x = CursorPoint.getX(); 
                  double y = CursorPoint.getY(); 
                 Line2D.Double current =                                                         new Line2D.Double(p1.getX(),p1.getY(),p2.getX(),p2.getY()) ;

                  if(current.intersectsLine(x, y, x, y))
                  { setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR)); 
                  } else {  setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));   
                   } 
                   repaint();
                     });
                    }

                  }

                  }, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    wallsEdit.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    wallsEdit.setVisible(true);
    wallsEdit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

and of course this doesnt work. so tried another thing. i declared my Wall class extends Component and implements mouseMotionListener and MouseListener. inside I wrote the mouseMoved event like for the panel .

hope that i gave all needed details . any help would be appreciated thank you very much

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code you have tried so far? (See also how to create a [minimal, verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).) That would help to find the problem with your code.

Comment: I already did the edit and copied the code there thank you